# Create a download link in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I read about adding the route, add method to controller and use link_to to create a link when everything is done in the same application. But I have separate front-end and back-end projects. Back-end side rails application will take care of reading from database and returning excel file to frond-end. How can I get a download button in the front-end rails application working? In my test scenario I have created a download UI button, with a route and method in controller. I want to download an `xlsx` file located at `root/spec/test_data/myfile.xlsx` by clicking this button.

I tried creating a route, add method in controller :

```
def download
  workbook_path = File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), '../myfile.xlsx' )
  send_file(
    File.open( workbook_path ),
    filename: "myfile1.xlsx",
    type: "application/xlsx"
  )
end
```

I am getting this error

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /engine/app/controllers/my_engine/../myfile.xlsx
```

How can I download my local excel file just with a route and controller action? I dont have `show.html.erb` since I already have a download button created. I'm sorry if it seems incomplete question. I am using Rails 4.

Comment: The link seems to work. Correct the path to the xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the file to the `assets` folder in `app`
and then do something like

`workbook_path = File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '../../assets/myfile.xlsx')`

or
`workbook_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'myfile.xlsx')`

Comment: Thank you Xavier, moving to assets folder and 'File.join' worked. Since this application is a gem being run from a server, Rails.root.join doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your exact case use:

```
workbook_path = Rails.root.join('spec/test_data/myfile.xlsx')
```

But I would agree with Xavier that assets is a better approach